# Empty files uploaded in Android Native browser

Tags: javascript, android

I'm creating a website for mobile phones that resizes photos and uploads them.

```
$('#ImgPreview canvas').each(function(pIndex) {
    vFormData.append(pIndex, canvasToJpegBlob($(this)[0]), vIssueId +'-attachment0'+ pIndex +'.jpg');
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/ob/issuefileupload',
    data: vFormData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(pData) {
    window.location = '/issue?id='+ vIssueId;
}).fail(function(pJqXHR) {
    alert(My.Strings.UploadFailed);
});
```

This works in Chrome for Android and in Safari on iOS, but in the native Android browser, the files have a content-length of 0 and name Blob + a UID. When the file is added to the formdata the size also seems rather large (900k opposed to 50k in Chrome).

The canvasToJpegBlob function:

```
function canvasToJpegBlob(pCanvas) {
    var vMimeType = "image/jpeg",
        vDataURI,
        vByteString,
        vBlob,
        vArrayBuffer,
        vUint8Array, i,
        vBlobBuilder;

    vDataURI = pCanvas.toDataURL(vMimeType, 0.8);
    vByteString = atob(vDataURI.split(',')[1]);

    vArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(vByteString.length);
    vUint8Array = new Uint8Array(vArrayBuffer);
    for (i = 0; i < vByteString.length; i++) {
        vUint8Array[i] = vByteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    try {
        vBlob = new Blob([vUint8Array.buffer], {type : vMimeType});
    } catch(e) {
        window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
                             window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
                             window.MozBlobBuilder ||
                             window.MSBlobBuilder;

        if (e.name === 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder) {
            vBlobBuilder = new BlobBuilder();
            vBlobBuilder.append(vUint8Array.buffer);
            vBlob = vBlobBuilder.getBlob(vMimeType);
        } else if (e.name === 'InvalidStateError') {
            vBlob = new Blob([vUint8Array.buffer], {type : vMimeType});
        } else {
            alert(My.Strings.UnsupportedFile);
        }
    }

    return vBlob;
}
```

Is there any way to get this working in the native Android browser?

Comment: Hey, any chance you got this working, I'm stuck with the exact same issue!

Comment: No, haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: We've got the same issue here -- I've added a bounty.

Comment: seems no jpeg still on android? https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/33 .  the larger png (900kb) is probably normal operation...

Comment: This is an Android bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22441 - having the same issue myself.

Comment: Guys. Did you get any solution? Still facing the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also ran into this problem and needed to come up with a more generic solution as in some cases I won't have control over the server-side code.

Eventually I reached a solution that is almost completely transparent.  The approach was to polyfill the broken `FormData` with a blob that appends data in the necessary format for `multipart/form-data`.  It overrides XHR's `send()` with a version that reads the blob into a buffer that gets sent in the request.

Here's the main code:

```
var
    // Android native browser uploads blobs as 0 bytes, so we need a test for that
    needsFormDataShim = (function () {
        var bCheck = ~navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android')
                        && ~navigator.vendor.indexOf('Google')
                        && !~navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome');

        return bCheck && navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit\/(\d+)/).pop() <= 534;
    })(),

    // Test for constructing of blobs using new Blob()
    blobConstruct = !!(function () {
        try { return new Blob(); } catch (e) {}
    })(),

    // Fallback to BlobBuilder (deprecated)
    XBlob = blobConstruct ? window.Blob : function (parts, opts) {
        var bb = new (window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MSBlobBuilder);
        parts.forEach(function (p) {
            bb.append(p);
        });

        return bb.getBlob(opts ? opts.type : undefined);
    };

function FormDataShim () {
    var
        // Store a reference to this
        o = this,

        // Data to be sent
        parts = [],

        // Boundary parameter for separating the multipart values
        boundary = Array(21).join('-') + (+new Date() * (1e16*Math.random())).toString(36),

        // Store the current XHR send method so we can safely override it
        oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

    this.append = function (name, value, filename) {
        parts.push('--' + boundary + '\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="' + name + '"');

        if (value instanceof Blob) {
            parts.push('; filename="'+ (filename || 'blob') +'"\nContent-Type: ' + value.type + '\n\n');
            parts.push(value);
        }
        else {
            parts.push('\n\n' + value);
        }
        parts.push('\n');
    };

    // Override XHR send()
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (val) {
        var fr,
            data,
            oXHR = this;

        if (val === o) {
            // Append the final boundary string
            parts.push('--' + boundary + '--');

            // Create the blob
            data = new XBlob(parts);

            // Set up and read the blob into an array to be sent
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function () { oldSend.call(oXHR, fr.result); };
            fr.onerror = function (err) { throw err; };
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(data);

            // Set the multipart content type and boudary
            this.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = oldSend;
        }
        else {
            oldSend.call(this, val);
        }
    };
}
```

And just use it like so, calling `fd.append(name, value)` as normal afterwards:

```
var fd = needsFormDataShim ? new FormDataShim() : new FormData();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution. It's not working for me. My server fails to parse the request data. And in Chrome Inspector, the request payload looks like this (pasted beginning of it):

```
----------------------1e3xa79f9edc04cok0c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC

(1#%(:3=<9387@H\N@DWE78PmQW_bghg>Mqypdx\egcÿÛC//cB8Bcccccccccccc
```

whereas normally with FormData, the file data is hidden. FYI, I am forcing Chrome to use the shim for testing purposes. But the result is the same on Android 4.1.

Comment: Ok I got it working by using \r\n for instead of \n. It's in the HTTP spec to use carriage return (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4), and my server (Django) requires it to parse. My last note about Chrome displaying the binary file data still occurs, but it's probably a special case for FormData and is not impacting.

Comment: @jacob, glad you got it working. I'm away at the moment so I can't update the answer but feel free to hit the edit button. I'll take your advice and use carriage return in my own code when I get back. Cheers ;-)

Comment: Sure thing Andy. I just did that. And thanks again for your solution. It works like a charm!

Comment: @AndyE I would be interested into having this code into a "reviewable" gist. For instance, I'm wondering if 1/ we shouldn't put XHR.prototype.send = oldSend into a finally{} block and 2/ if we create 2 FormDataShim in a row, won't we have 2 decorations made on XHR thus never making consecutive val===o as being true

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to draw it on canvas, using matrix to scale it to the size you wish and then sending it to server using `canvas.toDataURL`. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876842/send-canvas-images-as-a-file-stream-html5).

Comment: I see that my question can be misunderstood. Edited it now to specify that this is for a mobile website, not an app.

Comment: @bjornarvh try my new solution

Comment: Got it to work by sending the image as a base64 encoded string instead. Marked this as answer since there seems to be no solution with normal file upload.

Comment: I can't confirm that base64 string is working. Browser seems to cut the end of the longer string

Answer (score 1):

i use this to fix the problem:

```
// not use blob, simply use key value
var form = new FormData();
// get you content type and raw data from data url
form.append( 'content_type', type);
form.append( 'content', raw);
```