# Sent Blob results empty

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

In a Cordova/Phonegap app that I'm testing on Android 4.0 I need to send a file to a server as `multipart/form-data` through ajax.

I have the file content in an `ArrayBuffer` and I put it in a `FormData`, firstly creating a `Blob` from it.

The problem is that the file sent appears to be empty.

This is a console session (performed on the Android platform through [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/)) where you can see that:

- the file content is already loaded in `mybuf`
- a `Blob` is created from `mybuf` (and its size is non-zero)
- a `FormData` object is created to be sent (`fd`)

*(I'm using `WebKitBlobBuilder` because the `Blob` constructor raises a `TypeError` on this platform)*

```
❯ mybuf
  ▼ ArrayBuffer
      byteLength: 23673
    ▶ __proto__: ArrayBuffer
❯ var bb = new WebKitBlobBuilder()
  undefined
❯ bb.append(mybuf)
  undefined
❯ myblob = bb.getBlob("image/jpeg")
  ▼ Blob
      size: 23673
      type: "image/jpeg"
    ▶ __proto__: Blob
❯ fd = new FormData()
  ▶ FormData
❯ fd.append("pics[]", myblob, "1433412118197.jpg")
  undefined
```

When I perform the ajax request passing the `fd` object as data, I see that the file is actually sent (I see `name="pics[]"` in the request), but its content is empty.

This is an echo of the request:

```
POST /test/post/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.88:50000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 212
Origin: file://
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarywFAAx1aqKBZ6uuOf
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; it-it; M-MP706I Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: it-IT, en-US
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7

------WebKitFormBoundarywFAAx1aqKBZ6uuOf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pics[]"; filename="Blobd380f922a76d4b03908c426487d2fa68"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarywFAAx1aqKBZ6uuOf--
```

## What I also tried

I also tried to build an `Uint8Array` from the `ArrayBuffer` and to build the Blob with it in several ways, but none worked. The `Uint8Array` seems to be ok:

```
❯ var myu8buf = new Uint8Array(mybuf)
  undefined
❯ myu8buf
  ▼ Uint8Array
      0: 255
      1: 216
      2: 255
      3: 225
      4: 1
      5: 20
      6: 69
      7: 120
      ...
```

Then, accordingly to what I append to the `BlobBuilder`, the Blob size varies:

- `bb.append([myu8buf])` - Blob size: 19
- `bb.append(myu8buf)` - Blob size: 19
- `bb.append([myu8buf.buffer])` - Blob size: 20
- `bb.append(myu8buf.buffer)` - Blob size: 23673

So the last one seems to be the right one, but if sent it behaves exactly like the original `ArrayBuffer` (i.e. empty file sent).

## File read and Ajax functions

This is the function I'm using to send the `FormData` (with jQuery):

```
function sendform(fd) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://192.168.1.88:50000/test/post/',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(d){
        console.log("data received:");
        console.log(d);
      },
      error: function(d) {
        console.log("ajax error!");
      }
    });
}
```

And this is the function to read the file content in an `ArrayBuffer`:

```
function file2buf(filename, callback) {

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filename, function(fileEntry) {

    return fileEntry.file(function(file) { // success (fileEntry.file)

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function(fileReadResult) {

        console.log("file type: "+file.type);
        console.log("file name: "+file.name);

        callback(fileReadResult.target.result);

      };

      return reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    }, function(e) { // fail (fileEntry.file)
      console.log("ERR in fileEntry.file");
      console.log(e);
    });
  }, function(e) { // fail (resolveLocalFileSystemURL)
    console.log("ERR in resolveLocalFileSystemURL");
    console.log(e);
  });

}
```

Comment: Seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639070/empty-files-uploaded-in-android-native-browser

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from a `FileEntry` or `Entry` (which is provided by the Camera).  You have to convert that entry to a Blob

Here's a method that will do it for you.  Note this loads the object into memory and I can't find a way of getting around that as there's no capability for streaming from the file system.

```
  private async fileEntryToBlob(entry: Entry): Promise<Blob> {

    if (!entry.isFile) {
      throw Error(`expected ${entry} to be a file`);
    }
    const fileEntry = (entry as FileEntry);
    return new Promise<Blob>(
      (resolve, reject) => {

        fileEntry.file(
          (file) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
              resolve(new Blob([evt.target.result]));
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          },
          (err) => { reject(err); },
        );

      });
  }
```

The blob can be appended into the `FormData` as shown here with promises.

```js
  /**
   * Uploads an artifact to the backend and returns a promise for
   * the upload result.  Progress cannot be tracked with this one.
   *
   * @param fileEntry file entry to upload
   */
  public async uploadFile(fileEntry: Entry): Promise<IUploadResult> {
    const url = ....

    const blob: Blob = await this.fileEntryToBlob(fileEntry);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("uploadFile", blob, fileEntry.name);
    return this.http
      .post<IUploadResult>(
      url,
      formData
    )
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Here is another one as an observable stream.

```js
 /**
   * Uploads an artifact to the backend and returns an observable of
   * HttpEvents.  That way progress can be tracked.
   *
   * @param fileEntry file entry to upload
   */
  public uploadFile$(fileEntry: Entry): Observable<HttpEvent<IUploadResult>> {
    const url = ...

    const formData$ = defer(async () => {
      const blob: Blob = await this.fileEntryToBlob(fileEntry);
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("uploadFile", blob, fileEntry.name);
      return formData;
    });

    return formData$.pipe(
      mergeMap(formData =>
        this.http
          .post<IUploadResult>(
          url,
          formData,
          {
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: "events",
          }
        )
      )
    )
  }
```